# Are there sequences that can not be expressed without a lookup table?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there sequences that do not have an expression (e.g. $f(n) =n^2$ for (1, 4, 9, 16)) or a recursive definition (e.g. $n = 2 n_{-1}$ for (1, 2, 4, 8)) to describe them?

Maybe (0,-6,10,-9,110,-29,107,-32)?

Comment: What about the sequence of prime numbers?

Comment: Browse the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](http://oeis.org).

Comment: For any reasonable definition of *expression* and *recursive definition*, there are only countably many of each, but there are uncountably many infinite sequences of integers.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott A surprisingly deep statement. Well put.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner . There is an elegant recursive formula (Ghandi's formula) for the primes but it has no practical use, because the expression  it uses to calculate the least odd prime $p\ge n$ has about $2^{\pi(n)}$ terms.